# How to use the options of MTKTextureLoader newTextureWithContentsOfURL?

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal, metalkit, mtktextureloader

I am trying to use MetalKit `newTextureWithContentsOfURL` to create the texture for a cow.

```
MTKTextureLoader *texture_loader = [[MTKTextureLoader alloc] initWithDevice:device];
NSURL *cow_image = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"spot_texture" withExtension:@"png"];
NSError *error;
diffuse_texture = [texture_loader newTextureWithContentsOfURL:cow_image options:nil error:&error];
```

Here is the sample cow (top) and my cow (bottom) look.

[image: Sample cow]

[image: My cow]

I don't know the reason about this, but I think the options may help.

How to set this option using `NSDictionary`?

Comment: I use NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@(YES) forKey:MTKTextureLoaderOptionOrigin]; and it work, but I still do not know what this code mean.

Comment: I'm surprised that that worked. That is the correct option name to use, but normally, you'd supply one of the origin values, such as `MTKTextureLoaderOriginFlippedVertically`, rather than an `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [Objective-C Literals](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

```
MTKTextureLoader *texture_loader = [[MTKTextureLoader alloc] initWithDevice:device];
NSURL *cow_image = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"spot_texture" 
withExtension:@"png"];
NSError *error;
diffuse_texture = [texture_loader newTextureWithContentsOfURL:cow_image options:@{ MTKTextureLoaderOptionSRGB : @true, MTKTextureLoaderOptionOrigin : @true} 
error:&error];
```